# Prototype js super method call or something like this

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Prototype js allows to call super method by $super. I need call class-method from object, but in overriden method, like this:

```
var ClassA = Class.Create({ 
  initialize: function(options) {
    Object.extend(this, options);
  },
  method1: function(){/*some code*/}
});

var ClassB = Class.Create(ClassA, {
  method1: function($super) {
    $super(); // this works fine, calls ClassA.method1()
  }
});

var objectA = new ClassA({
  method1: function($super) { // I need something like this
    $super(); // this not works, must calls ClassA.method1()
  }
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `objectA` is an instance of `ClassA`. Why do you redefine `method1`? `ClassA` does not inherit anything, so where should `$super()` go to?

Comment: I mean override method in object and can call not overrided method from class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my needs I find next decision:

```
function singleton() {
  var AnonymousClass = Class.create.apply(Class, arguments);
  return new AnonymousClass();
}
```

This function get me chance to override any method in class.
Example

```
singleton(ClassA, {
  method1: function($super) {
  /* call of $super() */
  }
})
```

This work for me as I wanted. Function returns for me object with overrided method from class, but this method can calls $super.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *just* `objectA` to have the new method, do this:

```
var objectA = new ClassA();

objectA.method1 = objectA.method1.wrap(function (fn) {
  fn(); // works like a `$super` call inside of a class
});
```

It uses [Function#wrap](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/wrap/) to add advice around the function.

If you need to pass arguments to the function, do this:

```
var objectA = new ClassA();

objectA.method1 = objectA.method1.wrap(function () {
  var args = $A(arguments), fn = args.shift();
  fn(args); // works like a `$super` call inside of a class
});
```

Comment: Thanx for you reply, it works fine too. P.S. And thanx for great framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redefine the method in an already defined Class you need to use `Class#addMethods`

```
var ClassA = Class.Create({ 
  initialize: function(options) {
    Object.extend(this, options);
  },
  method1: function(){/*some code*/}
});

ClassA.addMethods({
  method1: function() { 
    /** does something else **/
  }
});
```

However this will overwrite the `method1` method and not create a subclass or child method of the original one

http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/prototype/addMethods/

Comment: Thanx for your response, but it not exactly what I need. If I override method in class by 'addMethods', when I can't call not overrided method from parent.